# Creating a query with foreign keys and grouping by some data in Django

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I thought about my problem for days and i need a fresh view on this.

I am building a small application for a client for his deliveries.

```
# models.py - Clients app

class ClientPR(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                         choices=TITLE_LIST,
                         default='mr')

    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=65, verbose_name='Prénom')

    frequency = WeekdayField(default=[]) # Return a CommaSeparatedIntegerField from 0 for Monday to 6 for Sunday...

[...]


# models.py - Delivery app

class Truck(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Nom')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                         choices=COLORS,
                         default='green',
                         unique=True,
                         verbose_name='Couleur Associée')


class Order(models.Model):

    delivery = models.ForeignKey(OrderDelivery, verbose_name='Delivery')
    client = models.ForeignKey(ClientPR)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()


class OrderDelivery(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField(default=d.today())
    truck = models.ForeignKey(Truck, verbose_name='Camion', unique_for_date="date")
```

So i was trying to get a query and i got this one :

```
ClientPR.objects.today().filter(order__delivery__date=date.today())
                .order_by('order__delivery__truck', 'order__order')
```

But, i does not do what i really want.

I want to have a list of Client obj (query sets) group by truck and order by today's delivery order !
The thing is, i want to have EVERY clients for the day even if they are not in the delivery list and with filter, that cannot be it.

I can make a query with OrderDelivery model but i will only get the clients for the delivery, not all of them for the day...

Maybe i will need to do it with a Q object ? or even raw SQL ?
Maybe i have built my models relationships the wrong way ? Or i need to lower what i want to do... Well, for now, i need your help to see the problem with new eyes !

Thanks for those who will take some time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, i decided to go with 2 querys for one table.
One from OrderDelivery Queryset for getting a list of clients regroup by Trucks and another one from ClientPR Queryset for all the clients without a delivery set for them.

I that way, no problem !